# jQuery Parent height of Tallest Child on Load and Resize

Tags: jquery, wordpress, height, equals

I'm trying to get a ul (ul.testimonial) to equal the height of its tallest child li on load and window resize. One potential issue is that the lis are absolute divs and are phased in using query cycle. I'm loading the is script though Wordpress, but it doesn't seem to be working:-

```
<script>
function equalHeight(group) {
tallest = 0;
group.each(function() {
    thisHeight = $(this).height();
    if(thisHeight > tallest) {
        tallest = thisHeight;
    }
});
group.height(tallest);
}

jQuery(function($){
$(window).on('load', function(){
equalHeight($("ul.testimonial"));
});
 });

 $(window).bind('resize', function () { 
//$('ul.testimonial').css('height','auto');
equalHeight($("ul.testimonial"));
});
</script>
```

Can someone please let me know what's wrong with the code or perhaps a better way to do this?

Thanks

Glennyboy

Answer (score 0):

I found that this code worked for me in the end. I'm sure there are better out there, but it's pretty small and jt does work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(updateHolderSize);
jQuery(window).resize(updateHolderSize);

function updateHolderSize() {
var max = 0;
jQuery("ul.testimonial li").each(function () {
    max = Math.max(max, jQuery(this).height());
});
jQuery("ul.testimonial").height(max);
}
</script>
```

For my implementation in Wordpress this only worked with 'jQuery' rather than '$'.

Cheers
Glennyboy

Comment: to make $ work wrap into `jQuery(function($){/*use $ here */});`